# Appexchange partner model for google chrome extension

Tags: appexchange, isv, licenses, chrome, oem

I want to list my google chrome extension on salesforce. The [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-data-exporter/fimhgbeiaffioifgjfcfjnphifipknao) is for exporting salesforce list data to CSV file.Which partner model should I use for this?

My target users are already using salesforce, so I don't want to sell a salesforce licence as well(as done in OEM, I guess).

The 'Get It Now' button in appexchange should redirect to [chrome extension page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-data-exporter/fimhgbeiaffioifgjfcfjnphifipknao). My extension includes a free trial of one month and I want to manage the billing from google web store. I am already paying fees per licence to google for this, do I also have to pay fees to salesforce, if I list on appexchange?

Comment: Is your extension a javascript based chrome extension that converts the SalesForce list view html into a CSV file?

Comment: It is based on javascript, but it doesn't work by converting html list to CSV file.

Comment: Is it purely a Chrome extension or does it rely on a Salesforce app as well?

Comment: It's purely a chrome extension. There is no salesforce component to be installed.

Comment: Honestly, I think that you're going to need an authoritative answer from the partner program team. From what I've seen of the ISV agreement, this type of app isn't covered, so it needs an official answer. Odds are you'll have to pay license fees in exchange for listing, or forgo listing and hope that Google's listing will suffice.

Comment: I will log a case with salesforce. There are many chrome extensions in appexchange already and some apps which just use salesforce API in their own web apps. So I think it may be possible. Also, salesforce charges fees per licence and in my case there is not going to be any salesforce licence. Let's see. I will update this thread with the salesforce's response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ISVForce category of the [2019 Partner Program Policies](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/PartnerProgramPolicies.ProgramYear2019-2018.9.12.pdf) would apply here:

> A Partner application that integrates to or makes use of any application, service or other product for which Partner collects fees is not a free application. (For example, an application is not a free application if it is provided under a “freemium” payment model or if it requires purchase of another application from the applicable Partner.) SFDC reserves the right in its sole discretion and at any time to determine whether an application is a free application for the purposes of these Program Policies

Trialware requires the following process:

> To create trials on the AppExchange, your app or component must:
>
> Be a managed package
>
> Be managed via the License Management Application
>
> Autoprovision—that is, the user must not need to interact with you at any point to get the app or component up and running
>
> Have passed the security review
>
> Have passed the Trialforce template review

In addition, a Chrome extension which is not listed on the AppExchange but uses developer edition APIs would probably fall under the `freemium` language in the [MSA](https://developer.salesforce.com/files/trailhead-master-subscription-agreement.pdf):

> You are Commercially Distributing Your Application if installation, access, and/or use of any version of Your Application or its features and capabilities require the payment of fees of any kind to You (including, e.g., if Your Application integrates to or makes use of any application or other product or service for which You collect fees, or if the Your Application is provided under a "freemium” payment model).

**References**

- [Program Year 2019 Salesforce Partner Program Policies (pdf)](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/PartnerProgramPolicies.ProgramYear2019-2018.9.12.pdf)
- [Master Subscription Agreement - Salesforce Developers (pdf)](https://developer.salesforce.com/files/trailhead-master-subscription-agreement.pdf)
- [Provide a Free Trial on the AppExchange | ISVforce Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/free_trial_appexchange.htm)